# How to write hash ( key as column name and value as row ) into tab separated file using Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

Suppose I have hash content like this:

```
{
    'Name' => 'Jhon',
    'Roll No.' => '911',
    'Address' => 'CA',
    'City' => 'California', 
},
{
    'Name' => 'Jeff',
    'Roll No.' => '922',
    'Address' => 'CA',
    'City' => 'California', 
},
```

I want output like this:

```
Name    Roll No.    Address    City
Jhon    911    CA    California
Jeff    922    CA    California
```

What will be the easiest way to write csv like this without using any perl module?

Comment: Why would you arbitrarily give up tons of useful code by not using modules? Whenever I see someone saying "without using modules" it looks like they are saying "using only the left hand", or "with their eyes closed". You do know that you can always use modules, even if you do not have root access to the machine you are using.

Comment: Without using module because if the same functionality can be possible without module then why one should use it? Also, if we use module we need to install it in order to run that program. So always try to work with basic module. This way dependency will also reduce on module.

Comment: Why? Because the modules solve your problem the way it is meant to be solved, they are well tested and thorough. This is one of the many illusions about Perl, that you have to give up huge libraries to reduce dependencies. It just simply is not true. If you have permission to write files, you can use modules. Modules are just files with Perl code in them (or XS files).

Comment: Most of the time some modules are not available by default on most of the Operating System where as some Operating System does. Any non-technical person can simply run the script even if he does not have knowledge about Perl module and all. So this way it will be helpful for these type of peoples without installing module and simply running Perl script he can generate required result.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the arguments that people use to support the illusion. Perhaps there should be a question here on Stackoverflow about this, so we can debunk this myth once and for all.

Comment: Isn't that likely to hit 'too broad' or 'matter of opinion' and get closed? But yes, I would quite like that discussion. Not least because it gives _me_ ammunition when having that same discussion up the line. For better or for worse, I cannot freely download from CPAN and have to work within whatever 'system perl' I have on the systems I'm on. Which on RHEL5 is 5.8.8 and whatever was core then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hash slice to keep hash values in order,

```
my @keys = ("Name", "Roll No.", "Address", "City");

print join("\t", @keys), "\n";
for my $v (@AoH) {

  print join("\t", @$v{@keys}), "\n";
}
```